# Paypal subscription with no shipping address

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm developing a digital subscription model using Paypal's rest API. I'm following https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/ as well as referencing the API doc for more details.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to omit the shipping address requirement entirely. When the customer is on paypal's subscription approval page (on paypal.com), shipping address selection is always shown. I've already tried not entering `shipping_address` as well as omitting the tax `charge_model`. Neither of these change anything on the approval page. Companies like Netflix, Hulu, and all other sites I've checked don't require a shipping address when the customer is on the approval page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Within the subscription payload, just set the shipping option to `NO_SHIPPING` like so:

```
"shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING"
```

Here's an example of a complete payload:

```
subscriptionBodyPayload = {
                    "plan_id": `${subscriptionId}`,
                    "start_time": `${startDate}`,
                    "subscriber": {
                        "name": {
                            "given_name": `${first_name}`,
                        },
                        "email_address": `${userEmail}`
                    },
                    "application_context": {
                        "brand_name": "SerpWorx",
                        "locale": "en-US",
                        "shipping_preference": "NO_SHIPPING",
                        "user_action": "SUBSCRIBE_NOW",
                        "payment_method": {
                            "payer_selected": "PAYPAL",
                            "payee_preferred": "IMMEDIATE_PAYMENT_REQUIRED"
                        },
                        "return_url": "https://example.com/success/",
                        "cancel_url": "https://example.com/checkout/"
                    }
```